# Пример изоморфного приложения на nuxt js

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

Изучаю nuxt js, в принципе что-то получается и даже что-то работает, но есть небольшая путаница с vuex стором и actions. Посоветуйте где можно посмотреть примеры best practices изоморфного nuxt js приложения. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вот [ссылка](https://nuxtjs.org/examples) на официальные примеры

Вот [ссылка](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/07/16/7-tips-large-nuxt-app-vue/) на статью с "фишками" в NuxtJS